# How to get the last date of the month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the last date of the month based on solely the month number.

For example, if the month is indicated as "4" for April, I want it to return "4/30/2017".

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Is the 4 only that a 4 or is it a date that is formatted `m`

Comment: Get the date for the first of the following month, and subtract 1 (which in excel means 1 day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also supply the **year**, as leap year changes the last day of of February.  So:

```
=DATE(2017,A1+1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),A1,1),0)
```

As stated by Gary's Student you should provide the year in which you are looking, my formula uses the current year.  You can always change that to another cells variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=date(year(today()), a1 + 1, 1) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this formula, though it doesn't account for leap years. Be cautious of using methods with 'date' as they will use the current year, which will determine whether or not February gets 28/29. In some cases, you won't *want* that. Then you simply build the full date.

[In this case, A1 is the cell you're testing]

```
=IF(OR(A1=1,A1=3,A1=5,A1=7,A1=8,A1=10,A1=12),31,IF(A1=2,28,30))
```

Comment: What about leap year?  then 2 would not be `28` but `29`

Comment: As mentioned in the first sentence, it doesn't account for leap years. However, the original post said he's simply using a digit 1-12 to represent a month, no year included, there's not enough info to make that call. You could stack another IF in there and say if year is dividable by 4 (leap years just happen to fall that way) to have it separate 28/29.